# Rider JetBrains won't highlight syntax errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, syntax-highlighting, rider

I'm very new to programming and want to get into game development.

I just downloaded Unity and Rider on my mac, when installing the latter i installed all suggested plugins associated with Unity and c#. When i created my first script in Unity and opened it with Rider, i saw that it won't highlight any syntax errors. Scripts work fine in Unity if i write them correctly, but i want to be able to see suggestions and error highlighting from the IDE. 
[As you can see from the screenshot, i wrote some gibberish and it won't highlight any errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwhx7.png)

Power saving mode is off, highlighting level is set to max.

Comment: You merely opened a file in Rider, but not from a project. I doubt any IDE will be able to show errors in that way, as without a project it cannot compile and check errors. See "opens your Unity project" in https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/30/getting-started-rider-unity/

Comment: It turns out, i had to manually set Rider as external script editor in unity preferences, thank you everybody for your answers, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

set ide in unity preferences -> external tools -> external script editor

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingToolsIDEs.html

Answer (score 0):

For Unity 2019.2+ make sure:

1. You have recent version of Rider package in Unity
2. External Editor in Unity is Rider

Call Assets->Open C# project in Unity, it should open project in Rider.

Answer (score 0):

I had set up the external script editor in unity but the problem for me was the highlight level was set to minimum. Click on the pens (bottom right) to set it how you need (it can be only syntax errors, or as high as coding hints from the IDE)

[image: Configure highlight level]